# Replace and if/else

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

The question is:

> Create a function that accepts an array, and when you print the array
>   it shows that "yummy" has replaced every instance of the string
>   "food". If no array elements are present or there are no array
>   elements that say "food", then print "I am hungry" once.

The array I was given was:

> ["hello", 2,"Jay","food",34,34,"food"]

The algorithm I came up with looks like this:

```js
function alwaysHungry() {
  var arr = ["hello", 2,"Jay","food",34,34,"food"];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i] == "food"){
      arr[i]="yummy";
      console.log(arr);
    }
    else if (arr.length == 0 || arr[i] != "food"){
  
      console.log("I am hungry");
    
    }   
  }
    
}
alwaysHungry();
```

This is my output:

```
3VM578:12 I am hungry
VM578:8 (7) ["hello", 2, "Jay", "yummy", 34, 34, "food"]
2VM578:12 I am hungry
VM578:8 (7) ["hello", 2, "Jay", "yummy", 34, 34, "yummy"]
```

According to the array I have I should only see in my output ["hello", 2, "Jay", "yummy", 34, 34, "yummy"] and if I make the array empty I should see "I am hungry" but not both at the same time.

UPDATE

Alot of the examples below are giving me a print out of two lines it is supposed to print out the array or the statement "I am hungry" but not both at the same time.

Comment: Not critical, but could you indent your code for readability?

Comment: read it out loud `arr.length == 0 || arr[i] != "food"` .... If array's length is zero OR if the current index is not the string food than do the following

Comment: Also, your function does not fulfill the requirement "accepts an array". You're hard coding an array within the function.

Comment: Is it just me or shouldn't that output have a lot more I am hungry's than is shown in the output? following the current code that is

Comment: @Zannith `arr.length` is never 0, which short circuits the `||`.

Comment: @chuckx maybe i'm blind, but shouldn't that not short circuit because in the example the arr length is not 0 and `||` is an `or` in javascript correct. It would short circuit if it was an `and`

Comment: Whoops, you're right, I was thinking backwards. Maybe we're just looking at a subset of the output?

Comment: Edited the post to use the code snippet functionality, showing the full output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a flag and set the flag if an item with `'food'` is found. At the end check this flag and make the wanted output.

You need no extra check for the `length` of the array, because the flag gets the right start value and the `for` loop exits directly with the first condition.

For a more convenient use of the function, use a parameter of the function for the array.

```js
function alwaysHungry(array) {
    var i, hungry = true;
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] === "food") {
            array[i] = "yummy";
            hungry = false;
        }
    }
    if (hungry) {
        console.log("I am hungry");
    } else {
        console.log(array);
    }
}

alwaysHungry([]);
alwaysHungry(["hello", 2, "Jay", "food", 34, 34, "food"]);
alwaysHungry(["hello", 2, "Jay", "abc", 34, 34, "def"]);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This one is close the but the problem I am having is and its the same in your example is that it is printing, for example, in the last example it prints (7) ["hello", 2, "Jay", "abc", 34, 34, "def"]
I am hungry and it should print one line "I am hungry".

Comment: in the last is no `'food'`. it prints *"I am hungry"* what is wrong with it?

Comment: I think OP doesn't want to print the array when there is no "food" item

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want (If you are looking for `ES6` syntax):

```js
var inputArray1 = ["hello", 2,"Jay","food",34,34,"food"]
var inputArray3 = ["hello", 2,"Jay","foo",34,34,"boo"]
var inputArray2 = []

function foodFinder(arr) {
  return (   (arr.length == 0) || 
         (!arr.includes("food"))  ) ? 
                                   "I am hungry" 
                                   : arr.map(e => (e + '').includes("food") ? "yummy" : e)
}

console.log(foodFinder(inputArray1))
console.log(foodFinder(inputArray2))
console.log(foodFinder(inputArray3))
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var alwaysHungry = function(array)
{
 if(!array.length || !array.includes("food"))
 {
  return console.log("I am hungry");
 }

 console.log(array.map(function(item)
 {
  return item == "food" ? "yummy" : item;
 }));
}

alwaysHungry([]); // prints "I am hungry"
alwaysHungry(["hello", 2, "Jay", "food", 34, 34, "food"]); // prints ["hello", 2, "Jay", "yummy", 34, 34, "yummy"]
alwaysHungry(["hello", 2, "Jay", "yummy", 34, 34]); // prints "I am hungry"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you are looking for. The code is readable and gets the job done.

```js
const yummy = ['hello', 2, 'Jay', 'food', 34, 34, 'food'],
      test1 = ['food'],
      test2 = ['hello', 2, 'Jay', 'foo', 34, 34, 'boo'],
      test3 = []

function acceptsArray(arr) {
  if (arr.length < 1 || !arr.includes('food')) console.log('I am hungry')
  else {
    arr.forEach((item, index, array) => {
      if (item === 'food') array[index] = 'yummy'
    })
    console.log(arr)
  }
}

acceptsArray(yummy) // ['hello', 2, 'Jay', 'yummy', 34, 34, 'yummy']
acceptsArray(test1) // ['yummy']
acceptsArray(test2) // I am hungry
acceptsArray(test3) // I am hungry
```

Answer (score 0):

You could map the items and replace them, then check to see if `food` is in the array.

```js
const items = ["hello", 2, "Jay", "food", 34, 34, "food"]

let result = items.map(item => item == 'food' ? 'yummy' : item)

if (!result.includes('food') || result.length == 0) {
  console.log('I am hungry')
}

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Knowing I'm late, here is my input.

I used the standard `for` loops and no `ES6` functionality.

Usually, e.g. in college, lecturers expect you to know the inner workings of how methods like `.reduce()` work before they see that as acceptable. (That's in my college anyway).

---

We can use a counter `foodCounter` that accumulates the number of `"food"` strings in the array.

- The code stops executing if the array is empty
- Check if current element is a `string` and ignore-case.
- Edits the values that contain `"food"` in it
- Increment `foodCounter` if above statement is `true`
- Check at the end if the `foodCounter` is equal to `0`

```js
var arr  = [];
var arr1 = ["hello", 2, "Jay", "day", 34, 34, "day"];
var arr3 = ["hello", 2, "Jay", "fooD", 34, 34, "FOOd"];

function alwaysHungry(array) {
  let foodCounter = 0;
  
  // If array is not undefined
  if (!array) { console.log("I am hungry"); return; }
  // Iterate over the array
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    // If element is a string and element is 'food' (case-insensitive)
    if (typeof array[i] === 'string' && array[i].toLowerCase() === 'food') {
      array[i] = 'yummy'; // Replace string to 'yummy'
      foodCounter++;      // Increment counter
    }
  }
  if (foodCounter === 0) { console.log("I am hungry"); }
}

console.log("No array");
alwaysHungry();

console.log("\nEmpty array");
alwaysHungry(arr);

console.log("\nNo 'food'");
alwaysHungry(arr1);

console.log("\nHas 'food'");
alwaysHungry(arr3);
```

Comment: This one is the closest, however, when I change the array and remove food so it just looks like ["hello", 2, "Jay", 34, 34] it should just print out "I am hungry", however, it is printing out the array and "I am hungry".

Comment: Still prints out double lines i.e. I am hungry and an array.

Comment: It's there for demonstration. You can simply remove it from the function. @JermaineSubia :)

Answer (score -1):

Through experimenting with all of the examples I was able to come up with the following:

```
function hungry(arr){
  var count = 0;
  for(var i =0; i<arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i] == "food" || arr[i] == "Food"){
    count++;
    arr[i] = "yummy";
    }
  }
  if(count <=0){
    console.log("I am hungry");
  }
  else{
    console.log(arr);
  }
}
hungry(["hello", 2, "jay", "food", 34, 34, "food"]);
hungry([2,5,7,8,3,2, "string"]);
hungry([]);
```

And the output is:

```
(7) ["hello", 2, "jay", "yummy", 34, 34, "yummy"]
I am hungry
I am hungry
```

Comment: check out my answer. it solves your problem in a readable, succinct manner